# Securely running a Spark application inside a Sandbox,

Tags: scala, security, apache-spark, sandbox

I want to execute untrusted code in an application that uses Spark. How can i create and run a Spark application inside a Sandbox, to securely execute custom code?

I tried using JVM sandbox. But due to permission issues i couldn't create a Spark Context successfully.

I am new to this area, and i really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.
Most of the articles with those keywords, talk about executing spark application in available sandboxes like Cloudera and HortonWorks, which i don't find related to my problem or they don't discuss anything about security.

Can somebody advice me about how to execute a Spark application inside a Sandbox which is created programmatically (something like JVM Sandbox or any other), or any other way to solve this problem?